# Why am I not allowed to put the image charge in the region where I want to calculate electrostatic potential?

Tags: electrostatics, method-of-images

I just want a rigorous explanation to why I'm not allowed to put an image charge in the region where I want to calculate the electrostatic potential. I know intuitively why it's true, but in Griffith's electrodynamics, he says this will make me solve Poisson's equation over the wrong source. I don't really understand this statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method of images works when you have more than one charge distribution that could lead to the same potential $\phi(x,y,z)$ on the **other** side of a boundary (with the usual boundary conditions). For example - in the classic parallel plates example you can get the same potential above the plate from either (1) a specific surface charge density on the plate or (2) an equally placed opposite charge.

However inside the region of interest, there is **only** one $\rho(x,y,z)$ that satisfies $\nabla \phi = \rho/\epsilon_0 $ according to the [uniqueness theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniqueness_theorem_for_Poisson%27s_equation). The only reason the uniqueness theorem doesn't apply to situations like the charge above a conducting plane is that there is a **discontinuous boundary** across which poisson's equation must be solved independently.

Comment: How do I express Poisson's equation for a point charge when it's charge density is infinite?

Comment: Its a delta function.